# Why doesn't the following JavaScript Regular Expression work?

Tags: javascript, regex

The Above Regular Expression Question was featured on [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/js10-regexp-2/problem),It should return true if string contains Mr./Mrs./Ms./Dr./Er. in the beginning followed by group of letters.

For Eg:
Mr.Abc is true but Mr.Abc. isn't
But my code returns Mr.Abc. as true.

```js
let inp="Mr.Abc.";
let re=new RegExp(/^Mr\.|^Ms\.|^Mrs\.|^Dr\.|^Er\.[A-Za-z]/);
console.log(re.test(inp));
```

P.S.Sorry for my Bad Regular Expression statement i'm currently in the learning stage ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a grouping problem, as well as an issue with the fact that you don't test for the end of the string using `$`. Using your expression, `Mr.Abc.` returns true because it matches `^Mr\.`

Change your expression as follows:

```
let re = /^(Mr|Ms|Mrs|Dr|Er)\.[A-Za-z]+$/;
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same thing and it resolved this issue with this simple change.

```
let re = new RegExp(/^Mr\.|^Ms\.|^Mrs\.|^Dr\.|^Er\.[A-Za-z]*$/);
```

This would make the search stringent while checking the string. Hope this helps :)

Comment: It might work for the specific case, but not for all cases. For example, your expression will also return true for the strings `Mr.`, `Dr.123`, and a whole lot of other cases that should not be matched.

Comment: Actually, this expression still matches `Mr.Abc.`, so the answer is incorrect.